# Tri-homogenous polynomials of tridegree $(3,3,3)$ to add three points on an elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties, algebraic-surfaces, divisors

Consider an elliptic curve $E \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ with the zero point $\mathcal{O}$. There are classical articles about complete systems of addition laws on $E$ (see
[Lange and Ruppert - Complete systems of addition laws on abelian varieties](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388526),
[Bosma - Complete systems of two addition laws for elliptic curves](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Ebosma/pubs/JNT1995.pdf)). It is known that the group law on $E$ can be represented by bi-homogenous polynomials of bidegree $(2, 2)$. More precisely, those articles show that for the divisor $D := 3(2V + 2H -\triangledown)$ the global section space $H^{0}(E^2, D)$ is non-zero, where $\triangledown$ is the anti-diagonal, $V := E \times \{\mathcal{O}\}$, and $H := \{\mathcal{O}\} \times E$. Moreover, $\lvert D\rvert$ is a base-point free linear system.

I am interested in the addition of three points $P := P_0 + P_1 + P_2$ on $E$. Of course, $P = (P_0 + P_1) + P_2$. However, expressing $P$ in this way
gives rise to tri-homogenous polynomials of tridegree $(4,4,2)$. Alternatively, I guess that there are tri-homogenous polynomials of tridegree $(3,3,3)$. Since $3\cdot 3 = 9 < 10 = 2\cdot 4+2$, it seems that the latter polynomials can be evaluated more efficiently. This may have applications in elliptic cryptography.

Now let $D := 3(3A_0 + 3A_1 + 3A_2 - B)$, where
$$
A_0 := \{\mathcal{O}\} \times E^2, \quad A_1 := E \times \{\mathcal{O}\} \times E, 
\quad A_2 := E^2 \times \{\mathcal{O}\}, \quad B := \big\{(P_0, P_1, -P_0-P_1)\big\} \quad \subset \quad E^3.
$$
If I am not mistaken, to confirm my conjecture it is necessary to prove that the space $H^{0}(E^3, D)$ is non-zero. Help me please to do this. And what about base-point freeness of $\lvert D\rvert$?

Comment: Another reference is Kohel '"Addition law structure of elliptic curves", Journal of Number Theory 131 (2011). On $E^3$ you also have the theorem of the cube, in particular $\mathcal{O}(B)$ is isomorphic to a product of line bundles which are pull-backs under some projection $E^3 \to E^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divisor $D$ is rationally equivalent to an effective divisor, hence $H^0(E^3,D) \neq 0$.

To see this, let $p_0,p_1,p_2 \colon E^3 \to E$ be the canonical projections. For $i,j \in \{0,1,2\}$, write $p_{i,j}=p_i+p_j$. By the theorem of the cube [1, Corollary 6.4], $B$ is rationally equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
B \sim p_{0,1}^* (0) + p_{0,2}^* (0) + p_{1,2}^* (0) - A_0 - A_1 - A_2.
\end{equation*}
Moreover, on $E \times E$ we have the relation $\Delta + \nabla - 2H -2V \sim 0$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal, $\nabla = \{(x,y) \in E \times E: x+y=0\}$ is the anti-diagonal, $H = E \times \{0\}$ and $V = \{0\} \times E$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
D & \sim 3 (3A_0+3A_1+3A_2 - p_{0,1}^*(0) - p_{0,2}^*(0) - p_{1,2}^*(0) +A_0+A_1+A_2) \\
& \sim 3 \bigl(4A_0+4A_1+4A_2 - (2A_1+2A_0-\Delta_{0,1}) - (2A_2+2A_0-\Delta_{0,2}) - (2A_2+2A_1-\Delta_{1,2})\bigr) \\
& = 3 (\Delta_{0,1} + \Delta_{0,2} + \Delta_{1,2}),
\end{align*}
where $\Delta_{i,j} = p_{i,j}^* \Delta$ is the pull-back of the diagonal under the projection $p_{i,j} \colon E^3 \to E^2$ onto the factors with indices $i,j$. This proves the claim.

**[1]** Milne, J. S. Abelian varieties. Arithmetic geometry (Storrs, Conn., 1984), 103–150, Springer, New York, 1986.

Comment: thank you! The next step is to find explicitly a non-zero section from $H^0(E^3, D)$. Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: @DimitriKoshelev I haven't thought about this question, but long time ago, I did some computation for elliptic curves represented as intersection of 2 quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^3$, with law of bidegree $(2,2)$. I wrote a [short note](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/francois.brunault/recherche/biquadratique.pdf), maybe you can adapt it to your case.

Comment: It seems one necessary step is to make explicit the theorem of the cube as in your [other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422014/a-constructive-proof-of-the-theorem-of-the-cube). I don't know how to do it but this is an interesting question.